# Exclude certain modules in deep rendering

Tags: enzyme, jestjs, enzyme-to-snapshot

I'm using jest snapshot comparison in combination with enzyme mount rendering. Is it possible to define a list of components which will be excluded from deep rendering?

Comment: How about mocking them?

Comment: I don't want that. I want the component to have its real functionality, response to events and run its code normally. I just want to stop deep rendering for it.